# rails app - can't get div to refresh with jquery/js

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a rails app where I can't seem to get a Div to refresh.

The div is in bedsheet_lines_index.html.erb

```
<div id="end_time_partial"  class="end_time_partial">
    <%= render :partial  => '/bedsheet_lines/end_time_partial', locals: { end_time:  3081 } %>
</div>
```

I am using a pop up form for the date. The link to that in bedsheet_lines_index.html.erb is

```
     <%= link_to( '<button>Edit end time</button>'.html_safe,

                       end_time_form_path(:id => 3081),
                       'data-popup' => true,
                       :remote => true,
                       :class => "button_class",
                       :onclick=>"window.open(this.href,'Edit end date', 'scrollbars=1,resizable=1,height=500, width=800, left=400, top=200');
                                 return false;"
              ) %><br>
```

end_time_form.html.erb has

```
<%= form_tag(controller: 'bedsheet_lines', action: 'end_time_partial_submit', method: "post", id: 3081, :remote => true)  do %>

     <%= text_field_tag(:end_time, end_time_temp, id: 'dpt')%>

  <%= submit_tag  "submit" %>
```

bedsheet_line_controller

```
  def end_time_form
     @bedsheet_line = BedsheetLine.find(3081)
     render :layout => 'alternate_style'
  end


def end_time_partial_submit
    {Non essential lines removed]
    @bedsheet_line = BedsheetLine.find(3081)
    @bedsheet_line.update_attributes(:end_time => parsed_end_time)

    respond_to do |format|   
        format.js { render :file => "bedsheet_lines/end_time_partial.js.erb" }
        format.html { render '/shared/window_closer'}
    end

end


 def end_time_partial
    @bedsheet_line = BedsheetLine.find(3081)
    render :layout => 'alternate'
 end
```

end_time_partial_submit.js.erb

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#end_time_partial').html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'test_partial', locals: { end_time:  $end_time  } ) %>");
    alert("BINGO2");
});
```

I put the alert of BINGO2 in the end_time_partial_submit to see if it is getting to that part of the code but it is not popping an alert box

window_closer.html.erb is

```
<%= javascript_tag do %>

    $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#end_time_partial').html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'bedsheet_lines/test_partial', locals: { end_time:  $end_time  } )) %>");

    });
   alert("more doughnuts");
   window.close();
<% end %>
```

I put an alert there also and that code does get executed (I see the 'more doughnuts' alert

My main objective is to refresh the div after updating a date.

--------- edit----

When I hit submit, the div does not refresh. If I refresh the page, then everything including the div is refreshed.

Comment: if you are only trying to set a date: may i suggest jquery date picker?

Comment: I am using best in place editing for inline editing. I had tried to switch the default datepicker but that didn't see to work. Even if it worked for the date, I have a similar issue with the comments where I am doing some tweaking of the text area field combined with a dropdown. That leaves me with the need to get the refresh to work.

Answer (score 0):

That line looks wrong for me... not sure if it's exactly how it is on your project.

```
$('#end_time_partial').html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'test_partial', locals: { end_time:  $end_time  } ) %>");
```

If it is an exact reproduction, I guess it raises an error 500 on server, complaining that `end_time` is Nil

Maybe you wanted `@end_time`.

I could suggest other modifications though... like use the other form of link_to

```
<%= link_to(end_time_form_path(:id => 3081),
                   'data-popup' => true,
                   :remote => true,
                   :class => "button_class",
                   :onclick=>"window.open(this.href,'Edit end date', 'scrollbars=1,resizable=1,height=500, width=800, left=400, top=200');
                             return false;"
           ) do %>
    <button>Edit end time</button>
<% end %>
```

That way you don't need pass a string with `html_safe`. And you can have an entire any html block inside it

Actually... as you only want a button... you could use `button_to` instead of `link_to`

But as I said... these modifications doesn't affect your problem... the only thing that looks wrong is the `$end_date` variable...

Comment: yes, even `@end_date` isn't set. He needs to use `@bedsheet_line.end_date`